# Dispatching redux actions inside custom serviceWorker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, service-worker

I want to perform actions on push received from server. I have a custom service worker which has the event listener for push. Now i want to dispatch redux actions when i recieve the push from server. My custom service worker lives inside public folder at the moment. And i am unable to import the store inside this file. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to dispatch Redux actions **inside** your Service Worker code.

However, what you actually want to do, is communicate using the postMessage API. Using postMessage, you can send the browser JS context a message when the SW receives a push from the server. You can find more info eg. here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage.

Why is it like this?
This is a consequence of the different execution contexts. Your normal JS code (React, Redux, actions etc.) run in **the browser context** where as your Service Code runs in **the SW context**. Those two contexes don't share **ANY** variables or state. For that reason, you cannot call any functions (eg. Redux actions) inside your SW code. You need to communicate between the two contexes and then, upon receiving a message in the browser context, call whatever functions you wish.

Comment: Thanks alot. I was stuck on it for more than a day. Now i have some direction to move.